Can't read several character from serial connection
I'm trying to setup a communication with an Arduino Nano. The arduino sends a single character every seconds.
In this question I was trying to read data from a serial port.
I thought I was out of the woods with the bit of code I found on the internet, but it actually doesn't work as expected.
For instance, in this code, if the arduino sends more than one character then ReadFile returns FALSE and GetLastError() returns ERROR_IO_PENDING
Here the arduino is sending 3 'p' characters every second.
It goes well the first time and then I have the error and I can get only 2 characters.
Here is the console output :
event 0x1 rxchar
ppp
event 0x1 rxchar
-ReadFile returned ERROR_IO_PENDING
event 0x1 rxchar
pp
event 0x1 rxchar
-ReadFile returned ERROR_IO_PENDING
event 0x1 rxchar
pp
event 0x1 rxchar
-ReadFile returned ERROR_IO_PENDING

And the program :
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define EXIT_ON_ERROR(hres, line)  \
if (FAILED(hres)) { \
std::cout << "error line " << line << std::endl; \
}
#define SAFE_RELEASE(punk)  \
if ((punk) != NULL)  \
{ (punk)->Release(); (punk) = NULL; }

void ReportStatusEvent(HANDLE port, DWORD s)
{
    printf("event 0x%lx", s);

    if (s & EV_ERR) {
        DWORD errors;
        COMSTAT stat;
        printf(" err");
        BOOL success = ClearCommError(port, &errors, &stat);
        if (success)
        {
            if (errors & CE_BREAK) { printf(" break"); }
            if (errors & CE_FRAME) { printf(" frame"); }
            if (errors & CE_OVERRUN) { printf(" overrun"); }
            if (errors & CE_RXOVER) { printf(" rxover"); }
            if (errors & CE_RXPARITY) { printf(" rxparity"); }

            assert(0 == (errors & ~(CE_BREAK | CE_FRAME |
                CE_OVERRUN | CE_RXOVER | CE_RXPARITY)));
        }
    }

    if (s & EV_RING) { printf(" ring"); }

    if (s & EV_RXCHAR) { printf(" rxchar"); }

    if (s & EV_BREAK) { printf(" break"); }

    if (s & EV_CTS) { printf(" cts"); }

    if (s & EV_DSR) { printf(" dsr"); }

    if (s & EV_RLSD) { printf(" rlsd"); }

    if (s & EV_RXFLAG) { printf(" rxflag"); }

    if (s & EV_TXEMPTY) { printf(" txempty"); }

    printf("\n");


}

void readAndDisplayByteByByte(HANDLE port, OVERLAPPED osStatus) {
    char read[100] = { 0 };
    DWORD numberRead;

    if (!ReadFile(port, read, sizeof(read), &numberRead, &osStatus)) {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            printf("Trying to read when still ERROR_IO_PENDING\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("--error no ERROR_IO_PENDING\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("lu %lu bytes\n", numberRead);
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < numberRead; i++) {
            printf("%c", read[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void readAndDisplay(HANDLE hComm, OVERLAPPED o, DWORD dwEvtMask) {
    char read[100] = { 0 };
    DWORD numberRead;
    BOOL Status;
    if (dwEvtMask & EV_RXCHAR) {
        if (!ReadFile(hComm, read, sizeof(read), &numberRead, &o)) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                printf("-ReadFile returned ERROR_IO_PENDING\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("-readfile failed with code %d\n", GetLastError());
            }
        }
        else {
            if (numberRead > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    printf("%c", read[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    ResetEvent(o.hEvent);
}

int main() {
    HANDLE hComm = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\COM4", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);
    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open port.  Error %d\n", error);
        return 1;
    }

    OVERLAPPED osReader = { 0 }; // Overlapped structure
    DWORD dwEvtMask;
    BOOL fWaitingOnMask = FALSE;

    // Initialize the OVERLAPPED structure
    osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    // Set device parameters (9600 baud, 1 start bit, 1 stop bit, no parity)
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (!GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams)) {
        printf("Error getting device state\n");
        CloseHandle(hComm);
        return 1;
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    //dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    //dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    //dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

    if (!SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams)) {
        printf("Error setting device parameters\n");
        CloseHandle(hComm);
        return 1;
    }


    //Setting Timeouts
    //COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };  //Initializing timeouts structure
    //timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    //timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    //timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    //timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    //timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    //if (SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts) == FALSE)
    //{
    //    printf_s("\nError to Setting Time outs");
    //    CloseHandle(hComm);
    //}

    // Set the event mask to wait for a character to be received
    if (!SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR)) {
        printf("error mask %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    DWORD lpErrors;
    COMSTAT lpStat;
    BOOL waitingOnMask = FALSE;
    ClearCommError(hComm, &lpErrors, &lpStat);
    while (1) {
        if (!waitingOnMask) {
            // Wait for an event to occur
            if (WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEvtMask, &osReader)) {
                ReportStatusEvent(hComm, dwEvtMask);
                readAndDisplay(hComm, osReader, dwEvtMask);
                //readAndDisplayByteByByte(hComm, osReader);
            }
            else {
                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                    waitingOnMask = TRUE;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Fatal error %d\n", GetLastError());
                }
            }
        }
        if (waitingOnMask) {
            DWORD res = WaitForSingleObject(osReader.hEvent, INFINITE);

            switch (res) {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                waitingOnMask = FALSE;
                if (dwEvtMask & EV_RXCHAR) {
                    ReportStatusEvent(hComm, dwEvtMask);
                    readAndDisplay(hComm, osReader, dwEvtMask);
                    //readAndDisplayByteByByte(hComm, osReader);
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("error waiting %d\n", GetLastError());
                break;
            }
        }


    }
    // Clean up
    CloseHandle(osReader.hEvent);

    return 0;


}

I tryied to fiddle with this quite a lot, to no avail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile

Is there any particular reason that you are reading asynchronously, or are you doing that just because that what the code you found does? It makes things much more complex.

john the reason I'm using asynchronous is because I want the thread to be able to do something else when the comm port isn't sending anything, such as writing to the comm port.

I understand that readFile returns false and that the last error will be ERROR_IO_PENDING but in this case the program is supposed to stay stuck on the WaitForSingleObject if the EV_RXCHAR event is triggered right ? So why is it returning false ? And why would I only have 2 characters instead of 3 ?
